# Powershell - Remove all properties in a registry item

Tags: powershell, registry

The following functions actually does the trick:

```
function Remove-AllItemProperties([String] $path) {
    Get-ItemProperty $path | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Foreach-Object {
        if (("PSChildName","PSDrive","PSParentPath","PSPath","PSProvider") -notcontains $_.Name) {
            Remove-itemproperty -path $path -Name $_.Name
        }
    }
}
```

For example: To delete all typed urls from the registry you can use

```
Remove-AllItemProperties("HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs")
```

My Problems are:

1. Since im relatively new to Powershell: I wonder if there is not a more beautiful (i.e. compact solution for the problem.
2. The functions throws an error if the item (registry key) has no properties (Get-Member complains about a missing object).

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I wonder if there is not a more beautiful (i.e. compact solution for the problem.

I would simply use `Remove-ItemProperty -Name *`:

```
function Remove-AllItemProperties
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([string]$Path)

    Remove-ItemProperty -Name * @PSBoundParameters
}
```

`Remove-ItemProperty -Name *` will remove any existing value in the registry key at `$Path`.

The `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute will automatically add Common Parameters (`-Verbose`, `-Debug`, `-ErrorAction` etc.) to your function.

By splatting `$PSBoundParameters` to the inner call, you automatically pass these options directly to `Remove-ItemProperty`

> The functions throws an error if the item (registry key) has no properties (Get-Member complains about a missing object).

The above approach won't have that problem

Comment: Thanks Mathias! As compact and as elegant as one can be. Also thank you for your detailed explanation...